# Как собрать проект с файлами .vala из Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Хочу добавить в VS2013 поддержку сборки файлов на языке Vala. Файлы .vala по плану должны транслироваться в .c и потом компилироваться с остальными .c исходниками.

Проблема в том, что транслятору Vala необходимо передавать файлы .vala все сразу какие есть в проекте. Т.е. транслятор вызывается 1 раз и обновляет из всех .vala файлов соответствующие .c файлы.

Насколько я знаю, подключаемые пользовательские инструменты работают отдельно с каждым файлом: 1.c -> 1.obj, 2.c -> 2.obj. Как быть в моем случае?

Можно расширить вопрос так: как можно с помощью Visual Studio и MSBuild скоппилировать файлы .vala?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно собрать компилятор vala для венды из под линуха. А потом уже говорить о компиляции файлов vala из под венды.